# Can I install android app in internal storage and upload it's content in SDcard?

Tags: android

Can I install an android app in internal storage and upload it's content in SD-card?
And if this is possible,
how to access to that content from app?
please, advice to me

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "upload its content in SD-card"? Do you want to write some data from the app to the sd card?

Comment: yes
suppose, some files of app are multimedia that user can download from internet. now i want to know, can app access to this files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can. The Sd card is open to every process. 
See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to learn how to get access to SD card.

Reminder: These files could be deleted by the user and are out of your control. You may remind the users that the app needs these files.

Comment: thanks for answer,
do you have another way for this problem or new suggest?

Comment: another way?your question is to read files on the SD card, not a design pattern or an algorithm, so I don't think there is some other way...

Comment: I'm sorry
this mean that are another way to keep content of app?

Comment: Since you could put the data either in sd card or in the internal storage, if you don't want to store it in sd card, your only choice is to store it in the internal storage. In that case, it's hard for the user to modify or delete the files(if user roots the phone, he is able too). Generally,multimedia files are a bit large, storing in the internal storage may not be a good idea.

Comment: If you concern the security of the files, you can crypt and decrypt them(there are some posts regarding to this topic in this site). You can also fetch them via Internet and don't store them locally, but this requires internet connection, and thus is not convenient.

Answer (score -1):

Yes in short. Long answer look up data storage for android.